# Change ViewContainer size height

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a ViewContainer in my ViewControler, and I wanted to ask you guys if it's possible to change the size of the ViewContainer (change the height over a gesture) when the app is running.

Thanks!

Comment: what actually you want and tell us what you tried?

Comment: Sure you can. Alter its frame property.

Answer (score 0):

You can change size of UIView of viewcontroller using below code
Call this method whenever you need to change frame size of view

Sample code below

Set view height to 100

```
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,100)];
```

To change height to 80

```
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,80)];
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is good, but static. 
I need it to change the height of the ViewContainer with a gesture with the finger.